# Is time-evolving wave function verified by direct measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

In quantum mechanics, if we know the initial wave function and the external potential, we can predict its wave function in any future point in time with Schrodinger's equation.

Is there direct measurement experiment to support this? That is, we setup a known initial state and a known potential (best to be time evolved), then we measure the possibility of the electron to be at some location and time in the future and the measured result is just the result predicted by Schrodinger's equation.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how electronic excitations are described in QM. Calculating the time dependence of the wavefunctions is utterly routine.

Comment: Would you please post some links of detail?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule

Comment: In the link I can't find any experiment that measure the wave function at some point,is that a "indirect" evidence ,too?

Comment: "Is there any" is more of the "prepared to disbelieve" I mentioned on a separate thread. You could have just asked "what are good references to experiments that show ...", but instead you've phrased it in an aggressive way that makes it rather less likely that you'll get the answers you're looking for. Can you see why the phrasing you've chosen is not constructive?

Comment: @ Emilio Pisanty Part of the question is "is there or not",because I never know one before and I'm not sure there is one because in many case there are no direct evidence for a theory.But you are right that it is smarter to use your phrase to talk to people.

Comment: You cannot measure the wave function directly. The result of a measurement of an observable can only be an eigenvalue of the operator corresponding to that observable. The best you can do is make the same measurement on multiple instances which are prepared in the same sate - the observed frequency of a given eigenvalue then gives you an estimate of the amplitude of the projection of the wave function onto the related eigenstate.

Comment: @ gandalf61 yes that is what I mean.We do the experiment for a lot of times and calculate a probability and compare it with the prediction.

Comment: @ gandalf61  Please check the question detail, I said "measure the possibility of the electron to be at some location", not the wave function it self.